# GridView for Monotouch

Tags: ipad, xcode4, xamarin.ios, aqgridview

I am trying to get a Visual Studio's gridview like control for Monotouch development. I had a look at AQGridView. Does AQGridView works with Monotouch? Is there a library for AQGridView which I can add to my monotouch project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use about any Objective-C library with MonoTouch.

You will just have to setup a MonoTouch binding project in order to use it.

Here is a link to another answer of mine that goes over it: [OpenFeint with MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869664/openfeint-with-monotouch/9871615#9871615)

Also read the Xamarin docs: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

Another UI library to look at is [Three20](http://three20.info/).  It's used in a lot of apps, like Facebook and Dropbox, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I have included the Three20.dll into my solution. Is there anything else I need to add to make the Three20.dll works with Monotouch? However, I am not seeing a table when I have the code as below in ViewDidLoad() method .......... Three20.TTTableView myTable =  new TTTableView(); 
myTable.Source = new SecuritiesExplorerDataSource();
this.Add(myTable);    ... Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You need to make a MonoTouch Binding project and fill out the bindings.  See my links above.

Comment: Here are the monotouch bindings for the AQGridView. https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.AQGridView

Answer (score 0):

I have created MonoTouch bindings for the AQGridView that should meet your needs.

https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.AQGridView

Just include the .csproj inside of your solution and add a reference to it.